# Getting the matrix value given a vector of indices along each axis

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab matrix M with size: [70     5     3     2    10     9     5     3    21];
I have a vector with a coordinates that I want to read of that matrix: [5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1];

MWE example of what I am trying to get:

```
M = rand(70     5     3     2    10     9     5     3    21);
coordinates =  [5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1];

% Output desired:
M(5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1)

%Current attempt:
M(coordinates)
```

Clearly `M(coordinates) <> M(5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1)`. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html

Comment: I do not think that is what I am looking for. I does not seem that on the function sub2ind I could do: 'ind = sub2ind(size(M), coordinates)' either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit awkward, but you can convert the array to a cell array, and then to a comma-separated list:

```
M = rand(70, 5, 3, 2, 10, 9, 5, 3, 21);
coordinates =  [5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1];

coords_cell = num2cell(coordinates);
result = M(coords_cell{:});
```